# Why doesn't setCentralWidget work?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is my class MainWindow :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    menu* v = new menu(this);
    setCentralWidget(v);
}
```

And my menu class :

```
menu::menu(MainWindow* parent){
    QLabel l = new QLabel("123");
    QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(l);
    this->setLayout(lay);
    QWidget* a = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout* lay2 = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel* ll = new QLabel("456");
    lay2->addWidget(ll);
    a->setLayout(lay2);
    parent->setCentralWidget(a);
}
```

When I run the program, the window shows 123 but I would like it to show 456.

Is the method `setCentralWidget` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setCentralWidget` works ok.
You are mixing up your widget `menu` construction with its position in an external widget (`MainWindow`). You should keep these thing well separated, or you won't be able, for example, to use `menu` inside other widgets.

So, you should set the appearance of `menu` in the constructor, and call `setCentralWidget` only in `MainWindow`.

It should look like:

file.h

```
menu::menu(QWidget* parent = 0);
```

file.cpp

```
menu::menu(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{   
    // Create items
    QLabel* l = new QLabel("123", this);
    QLabel* ll = new QLabel("456", this);

    // Put items in layout
    QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout();
    lay->addWidget(l);
    lay->addWidget(ll);

    // Set "lay" as the layout of this widget
    setLayout(lay);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since the wanted behavior is to have an interface that switch view according to button clicks:

[image]

the best option is to use a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Here a sample code the will produce this interface using `QStackedWidget`.

widget1.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET1
#define WIDGET1

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class Widget1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget1(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Button Widget 1", this);
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(btn);
        setLayout(layout);
        connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(buttonClicked()));
    }

signals:
    void buttonClicked();
};

#endif // WIDGET1
```

widget2.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET2
#define WIDGET2

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class Widget2 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget2(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        QPushButton* btn1 = new QPushButton("Button 1 Widget 2", this);
        QPushButton* btn2 = new QPushButton("Button 2 Widget 2", this);
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(btn1);
        layout->addWidget(btn2);
        setLayout(layout);
        connect(btn2, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(button2Clicked()));
    }

signals:
    void button1Clicked();
    void button2Clicked();
};

#endif // WIDGET2
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStackedWidget>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void buttonWidget1Clicked();
    void button2Widget2Clicked();
private:
    QStackedWidget* m_sw;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include "widget1.h"
#include "widget2.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // Create Widgets
    Widget1* w1 = new Widget1(this);
    Widget2* w2 = new Widget2(this);
    QLabel* w3 = new QLabel("Result", this);

    m_sw = new QStackedWidget(this);
    m_sw->addWidget(w1);
    m_sw->addWidget(w2);
    m_sw->addWidget(w3);

    setCentralWidget(m_sw);

    connect(w1, SIGNAL(buttonClicked()), this, SLOT(buttonWidget1Clicked()));
    connect(w2, SIGNAL(button2Clicked()), this, SLOT(button2Widget2Clicked()));
}

void MainWindow::buttonWidget1Clicked()
{
    m_sw->setCurrentIndex(1); // Will show Widget2
}

void MainWindow::button2Widget2Clicked()
{
    m_sw->setCurrentIndex(2); // Will show Widgee3
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

Comment: I want to test if it can call setCentralWidget in another class.

Comment: So I can never call setCentralWidget in another class?

Comment: I just want to find a method to switch QWidget.

Comment: how to implement switch window?
I want to know><

Comment: That's not good design. Explain what you want to do, and we'll find a better way to do it

Comment: I need a little more details.

Comment: Probably you are looking for a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html). You can switch view by setting the correspondent index (or widget)

Comment: I'm designing a system to manage students' score and course record
I want to have a user interface which can switch window when running sub widget

Comment: Before I see this, I'm confused with the use of QStackedWidget.
Thank you for your enthusiasm.
This code have great reference value to me.